# Game Center and iMessage for iOS9 vs. iOS10 multiplayer game?

Tags: ios, messages, game-center

Trying to play [Quatrian](https://quatrian.com/BGRTProduct.php)'s multiplayer app "[FaceMe Backgammon](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/faceme-backgammon/id407068826?mt=8)" between an iOS9 and an iOS10 client. How can I get these two to connect since the [changes to the Game Center and iMessage](http://appleinsider.com/articles/16/06/20/inside-ios-10-with-game-center-app-gone-invites-are-managed-by-messages)?

FWIW, the two are able to play Zynga's "Words with Friends" but that doesn't require the Game Center.

The iOS9 device sends invites to the emil and Game Center username of the iOS10 device, but they are not received.

The iOS 10 device has the Settings > Game Center but does not have an invite option.

The two can txt w/iMessage, but the iOS9 only has "Message".app (the green one, which receives iMessage - blue - data) and doesn't receive iOS10's iMessage invites.

The in-app multiplayer options are limited to Game Center "friends" but does not have the option of inviting.

The email response I got from the people at Quatrian deferred to [their "tips" page](https://quatrian.com/FMBGtips.php) (which does not address iOS10) and these fairly useless links:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5007662?tstart=0

http://appletoolbox.com/2015/10/ios-9-game-center-not-working-blank-page-fix/

Comment: Have you written to [Quatrian support](https://quatrian.com/feedback.php?id=3) to see if they are aware of the problem?

Comment: @IconDaemon Yes, I have. Unfortunately they have not been very helpful in finding a solution.

Comment: @IconDaemon they gave me this link: https://quatrian.com/FMBGtips.php which I have followed for iOS9, but it does not address iOS10

Comment: Sorry, @Mr. Kennedy. From what I've read around the net, Apple seems to be moving away from Game Center - there are no longer dedicated apps on either Sierra or iOS 10. Perhaps they quietly dropped some inter-app connectivity with these changes.

Comment: @IconDaemon thanks, I do appreciate your input. FWIW, AFAIK, Apple is just dropping the GameCenter.app and Apple is still supporting their "Game Center" - i.e. they've replaced the GameCenter.app's functionality with added functionality in iMessage. See here: http://appleinsider.com/articles/16/06/20/inside-ios-10-with-game-center-app-gone-invites-are-managed-by-messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after a bunch of back and forth with the Quatrain folks, I finally heard this from them:

> After a lot of investigation, it looks like there is no simple way to
>   add friends between iOS 9 and iOS 10 devices. We will be working to
>   integrate the new iOS 10 Game Center functionality, but it won't be
>   ready for a while as Apple made some drastic changes to the Game
>   Center functionality.
>
> As a workaround, you can play the Auto-match games and if you select
>   the Auto-Match Length of 5, you are almost guaranteed to only play
>   each-other as most players don't use that option.

My friend and I tried the simultaneous "Auto-Match Length of 5" option and were able to play backgammon together. While playing there are "send friend" invite options but mine "went out" to who knows where and theirs (iOS10) at least gave a message saying not available.

So, sounds like there's some work to do for app developers to maintain the new style of Apple's Game Center functionality with non-iOS10 devices.